# How to show the user can hover for more information

Tags: web-app, hover, data-tables

I have a simple table showing the configuration of various installs of a product. This particular product enables different profiles that enable/disable features and options. In this table, for each instance of an install, I list each of the profiles enabled. I want to use a [popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) to show some of the settings for that profile.

My question, then, is this: How can I best show the user that they can hover for more information? I originally thought to make it appear as a link, but would this confuse it for being clickable? I know the default `<abbr>` tag adds a dotted underline, is this the standard?

For example, listing profiles like so (ignore other data):

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv4W4e.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Are any of your users going to expect your table to work on devices that have no native hover capability such as 99.96% of phones and tablets unless it's a Galaxy Note with the S-Pen hover detection?

Answer (score 4):

Add an info icon next to the name and display a popup, on hover or click, to display any extra information.

[image]

Scott

Comment: The items that need the popups are each profile. For example the first row both default and alpha should have a (different) popup when hovering. Do you think having the info icon next to each would be a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally opt for making each profile item click-able and in the column header you can write something like:

> Profile (click a profile to view settings)

And now inside the popover() you can show the details.

Hover is not 100% accessible across all platforms.

Answer (score -1):

A dotted underline can also indicate that the mouse should hover (whereas a solid line means to click). This is the approach taken by the `<abbr></abbr>` tag in HTML.

To get a dotted underline you can use the following CSS:

```
[element] {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Obligatory [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8cgzr6n/).

Comment: You've not really covered off anything the user hasn't already stated in the question. Do you know whether users actually understand dotted underlines as meaning hover? And anyway, the `<abbr>` is for abbreviations not for hovering for more information. Re-appropriate it for another purpose will confuse screenreader users.

Comment: I don't think that it will be confusing to users. I certainly don't think that the code should be wrapped in `<abbr>` tags, but the mental processes involved are enough the same: A dotted underline should tell a user that more information can be found by hovering over the text. As far as I know, the text needs to be wrapped in an `<a>` tag for accessibility.